# Не нарушает ли хранение данных с использованием firebase закона о персональных данных?

Tags: firebase-database, google-cloud, облачное-хранилище, персональные-данные

В базе данных firebase хранится почта, телефон и фио пользователя. Как я понимаю, для хранения данных firebase использует google cloud. В ФЗ о персональных данных есть пункт о том, что данные должны храниться на территории РФ. Конкретно беспокоит этот пункт - не нарушает ли закон хранение данных на этом облачном сервисе?

Comment: No. It is **your** responsibility to store data where your laws require.

Comment: His question is exactly about his responsibility. In fact, he needs to know what is the location of Google cloud servers that keep firebase. Google keeps personal data of his Russian users in Russia but what is about any data of other databases that are used by Russian users?

Comment: @sergei - He is asking for legal opinion. He is responsible for determining that fact. Opinions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Сергей, не подскажете, где можно уточнить, что google хранит персональные данные на территории России ? Ничего не получается найти по этому вопросу

Comment: Не подскажу. Разве что сам Google запросить официально, если его firebase им официально предоставляется для сервиса российского (если не предоставляется, то 90%, что это за рубежом - зачем бы им сюда лишние серверы ставить?). Или спросить у Джона:-) (уж не знаю, кто он и почему тут на английском отвечает).

Comment: @JohnHanley, I do not know how have you understood that Boris needed in legal opinion. He definitely needs to know what is servers location (and he expressed it clearly later as you may see). (If somebody asks you: "Do you know what time is it?" - will you answer "yes, I know"? - thanks to Jerome Klapka Jerome for this example:-) Do you know where firebase servers are or how to get this info? P.s. And he did not blame Google, just asked for info.